# Cómo programar un bucle for con if y exportar las salidas?

Tags: r, bucle-for, condiciones, fortran

Tengo unos dataframes considerablemente grandes, pero un pequeño ejemplo de ellos es el siguiente:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("ES5163", "ES5167", "ES5168", "ES900),
                length_life= c("1820", "2223", 3858),
              año = c("2007","2008","2005"),
              cn = c("2","2","2"),
              ntrip = c("4","4","10","0")

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("ES5163", "ES5163", "ES5167", "ES5167", "ES5168","ES5168", "ES5168", "ES5168", 
 "ES5168", "ES900"),
                  change_time = c("1093","1460", "1093","1464","1145","1480","1052","1750","2356","2830","3233") 
                  camp = c("2008","2009","2009","2010","2009","2010","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010")
                  cn2 = c("1","3",,"1","2","1","3","4")
```

Y un vector que almacena los números 3 y 4

```
cols <- c(3, 4)
```

Debo hacer las siguientes comparaciones, utilizando un bucle for, pero no conozco la forma en que debo programarlo:

- Leer las columnas que almacenan la variable ID de los dos df.
- Sí df1$ID == df2$ID, que me escriba toda la fila del df1 correspondiente a ese ID y además
- Sí ntrip !=0, que me escriba en una fila más abajo: El elemento 1 del vector col más las columnas 2 y 3 del df2, luego el elemento 2 del vector más las columas 2 y 2 del df 2.

El fin último es exportar una salida que se tenga el siguiente formato:

[image: Salida/output]

La necesito en este formato, porque así la requiere un programa que debo utilizar luego con esos datos. Alguna idea de cómo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El código compartido no está bien (faltan comillas, la cantidad de elementos en cada columna son diferentes, etc.), pero algo así debería más o menos hacer el trabajo.

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table(df1)
df2 <- data.table(df2)
df3 <- merge.data.table(df1, df2, by = "ID")
for (cID in unique(df3[, ID])) {
  write.table(df1[ID == cID], col.names = F, row.names = F, quote = F)
  if (df1[ID == cID, ntrip] != 0) {
    write.table(cbind(cols = cols[1], df2[ID == cID, c(2, 3)]), col.names = F, row.names = F, quote = F)
    write.table(cbind(cols = cols[2], df2[ID == cID, c(2, 3)]), col.names = F, row.names = F, quote = F)
   }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Guile, una pregunta que puede que sea tonta, pero soy una inexperta. Cuál es la interpretación de la "c" que antepones a ID en el bucle?

Comment: es una variable, un vector... para diferenciarla de la columna